# Object reference error in Master Page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

I am getting the following error at runtime:

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." - the code in question in my code-behind is as follows:

```
Dim MinDateDataView As DataView = CType(SqlMinDate.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
Dim MinDateDataRowView As DataRowView = MinDateDataView.Item(0)
```

This is only a problem when it's used in a master page.  Can anyone help me out?  Thanks

Comment: Where are you initialize SqlMinDate?

Comment: Sorry didn't make that clear.  It's in the aspx page as a SqlDataSource. It compiles correctly but errors at runtime.  I'm assuming it's connected to master pages but after that I'm a bit lost.

Comment: I wil ask it different, where do you define the SqlMinDate variable and how you initialize it (default value of an Object is null)?

Comment: On the aspx page - this works perfectly well outside of master pages.  If you're saying I should initialise it first then I can look into that...

Comment: So I understand the init in the aspx page's PageLoad event. And where does the code you posted (in which event and in which page)?

Comment: No the SqlDataSource is on the aspx page - the code I posted is in the code behind (file.aspx.vb) in an onclick event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<SelectParameters>
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="ctl00$MainContent$txtSubID" Name="SubID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

Checking the html source I've used the master page control name, and it's worked.  Just came back to it after leaving it for a while, as is often the case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you perform SqlMinDate.DataBind() for the SqlDataSource?

Comment: I've added that line into my code behind immediately before I declare the dataview, and still nothing.

Comment: @ajguk: Try to make DataBind() to the dataview instead of the SqlDataSource.

Comment: From taking out the sqlmindate dataview I am now getting errors on each dataview I use.  Master pages seem to be causing null reference exceptions. Clearly my code behind can't find controls within the master page the way I'm coding it.

Comment: @ajguk: Can you post your aspx code and code behind of the relevant palces in the master page and the aspx page?